# Socket IO who can listen

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have implemented a socket.io webservice. My idea was to make multiple clients attach to the same socket and listen to the right messages.

So if client1 listened on the port for a emit of "testEmit1" and client2 listened for a emit of "testEmit2", only the first client would get the messages from a emit with the title "testEmit1". My question is: Is it possible to do a unfiltered listen on this port and just retrieve all the emits that come along?

Comment: socket.io does not offer wildcard listening or listening to all possible messages as a feature (not sure why).  There are some add-ons that add that feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this in two methods. Server side or Client side:

From Server side, just put different users to different rooms. Define and maintain your user-message logic list, and sent message accordingly to different rooms.

Or just put everyone in the same room. Broadcast all messages to all client. But on client js side, only show message with a title or this particular user.